# Directional Arrows

Tags: mapbox

I'm new to mapbox so any help would be great!
I have figured out how to import from google maps and create styles for the map but I am wondering how to show a route arrow on the direction line like the photo below?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqP0J.png)

Answer (score 0):

What platform are you building for? Web/JS, Android, or iOS?